# Uhh... I got drunk and trashed a temple. How do I pick up the mess?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After getting shouted at rather intensely by four old guys on the top of a "7000 steps" tall mountain, I decided it was time to go home to Whiterun and have a couple cups of mead.

Fortunately I found the right drinking buddy at the inn by the marketplace. He greeted me by offering me a drinking challenge. Who am I to say no? Well... as you can already guess, no good story starts with "that night when I decided not to drink...".

A couple of drinks later I woke up on the other side of Skyrim in a temple inside Markarth and was greeted by a priestess of the temple. My drinking buddy and the staff that he promised me for winning the drinking contest were nowhere to be found. Also, apparently I made a mess off the temple and now need to clean up.

I looked around and picked up everything that is on the floor, but when I try to talk to her she still says "Talk to me again when you picked up the mess that you made". What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You've probably missed something (I missed the note on the ground).

To have it pointed out to you, open your quest menu (J on PC) and press <kbd>E</kbd> on the quest that you just received (A Night to Remember), and a little arrow will appear over any items you missed both in world and on your compass.

Comment: There is a spell that helps you find the actual way to the quest target as well, shows a blue path on the floor.

Comment: @Konerak Correct, it's called Clairvoyance.

Comment: For me, the note was not rendering. Only when following this tip did I know which section of the floor to click on.

Answer (score 17):

It's probably the repair supplies note. It blends in almost perfectly with the light on the ground, though I did use clairvoyance to find it myself, if you walk in the front door of the temple and look on the floor to the right of the raised sancrum in front of the shrine, it should be on the floor. That's where it was for me