# What's the quest for Giant Toes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got a bunch of Giant Toes that I can't get rid of...it insists they're quest items.  But I don't think I have such a quest.  Can I start it somewhere so I can get rid of them?

Comment: Even if your quest only needs one item, the game will mark the entire stack as quest items, which can be quite annoying. My guess is you have a misc quest asking for one or two of those things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are used for the "Hangover" quest which starts with a drinking competition in which you black out and destroy a temple (see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/uhh-i-got-drunk-and-trashed-a-temple-how-do-i-pick-up-the-mess) if you need help).  One of the items needed to repair the staff is a Giant's Toe.

Comment: It appears to be an optional item in the quest, as I never had any need for it in the way I completed it.

Comment: @DoozerBlake As far as I know, you don't actually use it in the quest, however you do have to lug it around.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ahh. I guess I did have it around on me at the time, I just didn't try to sell it or get rid of it at the time during the quest.

Answer (score 4):

Skyrim has the annoying functionality that sometimes regular items can be quest items (Giant's Toes, Amulets of Talos), but they stack with their non-quest item selves, and you can't separate them.

To answer your question, Sanguine's Daedric Quest involves a quest-item Giant's toe. (See [Uhh... I got drunk and trashed a temple. How do I pick up the mess?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/uhh-i-got-drunk-and-trashed-a-temple-how-do-i-pick-up-the-mess))